# Getting Location out of a LocationResult in onReceive()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-location-services

My App uses **LocationServices** to request location updates. It sends the results via a **PendingIntent** to a **Receiver**. In **onReceive**()  a **LocationResult** is extracted  from the intent, which yields a **Location** that is then expressed in terms of **Lat** and **Lng**, to be used further. Sounds OK, right?

Well, the App started to crash with **NullPointerException**.

I investigated using **Debugger** and found that the three lines of code which I described above executed fine, but then, instead of proceeding to the following lines of code, execution was somehow directed back again to the first of the three lines, which extracts a **LocationResult** from an intent. This now turned out to be null, and crashed on the following line with **NullPointerException**, as  **LocationResult** was assumed not to be null.

I have no idea why this is happening. Any pointers, please? (Sorry for the pun)

Here is my code:

```
public class MyLocationUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationUpdateRcvr";

 // empty constructor
    public MyLocationUpdateReceiver(){}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG,"onReceive update");

        // extract locationResult from intent received from Update Request
        LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        double locationLat = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
        double locationLng = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();

        // send the Lat and Lng of new location to MapActivity via intent
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), 
        MapActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("New_Lat", locationLat);
        mIntent.putExtra("New_Lng", locationLng);
        mIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);

    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot of the first time through.Note the LocationResult is not null.

[image]

Still on the first time round...

[image]

and on the second time round...

[image]

Comment: May be your intent `null`.

Comment: The first time round it is not null

Answer (score 1):

Are there scenarios where you are putting extras into the PendingIntent? After some testing, I've found that this causes the location information to not be stored in the intent when it's passed to the receiver. It seems like they should be able to put the locations alongside the extras in your intent, but it's not implemented that way.

Comment: Yes I am passing extras to my intent. And as a result LocationResult.extractResult(intent); is null. If I don't pass extra then LocationResult.extractResult(intent); is not null. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using your receiver while registering in manifest. You need to use broadcast receivers with java coding i mean dynamic binding. For details how to bind you may refer below link.

[Dynamically registering a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776165/dynamically-registering-a-broadcast-receiver)

And secondly you can you can also try instead of passing intent as you passing LocationResult.extractResult(intent); evaluate intent in onReceive() method

Comment: i have registered the receiver in the Manifest and also dynamically in my code. Your second point was not clear to me what you meant.

Comment: I am trying to say you should try using intent locally.(locally means in the scope of onReceive).In short don't pass intent to other method to extract data use the intent in onReceive method boundary

Comment: how do I extract a LocationResult from the intent if not by using extractResult()?

Comment: ..also, it works fine the first time round. My question is why it suddenly goes back on itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the source of `LocationResult.extractResult` you'll see that it can return `null` regardless of the `@NonNull` annotation:

```
@NonNull
public static LocationResult extractResult(@NonNull Intent var0) {
   return !hasResult(var0) ? null : (LocationResult)var0.getParcelableExtra("com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT");
}
```

So you should be fine if you handle the return value as optional.

In my investigation a `null` value is returned if the user revokes "all-time" location access and returns to the app. The receiver will be invoked but the Intent is missing the `com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT` extra, hence the null value.

```
public static boolean hasResult(@NonNull Intent var0) {
   return var0 == null ? false : var0.hasExtra("com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT");
}
```

What you can find in the extras in this case is `com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_AVAILABILITY`, based on which you can decide how to handle the Intent.